# gdalwarp raster reprojection is generating pixelated edges

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, gdalwarp, goes-16

I have a raster image, which is satellite data, that I would like to reproject using `gdal` on the command line.

The files I am using can be found here:
[`the unprojected image`](https://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/data/gis/images/GOES/conus/channel13/GOES-16_C13.png) (.png)
[`.wld file`](https://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/data/gis/images/GOES/conus/channel13/GOES-16_C13.wld)
[`.msinc file`](https://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/data/gis/images/GOES/conus/channel13/GOES-16_C13.msinc)
[`json file containing metadata`](https://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/data/gis/images/GOES/conus/channel13/GOES-16_C13.json)

So far, I have been downloading the `png` and `wld` file into the same directory, extracting the proj4 string from the json file (in this case, it is `+proj=geos +h=35786023.0 +lon_0=-75.0 +sweep=x`), and running

```
gdalwarp -s_srs "+proj=geos +h=35786023.0 +lon_0=-75.0 +sweep=x" -t_srs EPSG:3857 unprojetedImage.png -srcnodata 0 -dstnodata 0 projectedImage.png
```

This gives me an image with pixelated edges:
[image]

However, if I load up the unprojected image into QGIS, it will detect the `wld` file in the same directory, and once I type in the proj4 string, it will render a much smoother image. It's not rearranging the pixels I don't think, it's just warping / skewing it - but it has a much nicer look:
[image]

Does anybody know how I can use `gdal` on the command line to reproject the initial raster into another raster, but have the output look a lot smoother like QGIS does somehow?

If that's not possible, does anybody know how to use `gdal` to generate the lat/lng coordinates of the 4 corners of the reprojected image, so I could allow a mapping library to do the skewing for me?

Comment: Rasters are made of rectangular pixels and gdalwarp cannot override that. Using smaller pixels is a poor workaround. Gdalwarp has options for blending if the warped image is written to update an existing raster https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html but I am not sure how nice result it gives. OSSIM was very good at feathering but I am not sure if the project is alive https://ydl.oregonstate.edu/pub/osgeo/download/ossim/docs/pdfs/HistogramVCE.pdf. Pixels are still rectangular after blending and feathering but the seam looks nicer because pixels values are changing gradually.